# Flex popup manager, mousedown outside of the popup removes the popup

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

If you create a popup via:

PopUpManager.addPopUp( popup, this, false );
PopUpManager.bringToFront( popup );

It will create a popup and bring it on top of any other visual piece. I have one problem though. This 'popup' needs to stay up even when the user interacts with the background.

I would use modal, but I need the ability to interact with the back. Any way to tell the popup manager not to remove the popup when the user clicks off of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a helper class which would help you (tested only in Flex 4, but probably could be changed for Flex 3 too):

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import mx.core.mx_internal;
import mx.managers.ISystemManager;
import mx.managers.systemClasses.ActiveWindowManager;

use namespace mx_internal;

public class PopupHelper
{
    private var popup : DisplayObject;
    private var systemManager : ISystemManager;
    public function PopupHelper(popup : DisplayObject, systemManager : ISystemManager) : void
    {
        this.popup = popup;
        this.systemManager = systemManager;
    }
    public function forceToFront() : void
    {
        systemManager.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onSystemMouseDown);
        popup.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onPopupRemoved)
    }
    private function onSystemMouseDown(e : MouseEvent) : void
    {
        bringToFront(popup);
    }
    private function onPopupRemoved(e : Event) : void
    {
        popup.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, onPopupRemoved);
        systemManager.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onSystemMouseDown);
    }
    private function bringToFront(popup : DisplayObject) : void
    {
        var windowManager : ActiveWindowManager = systemManager.getImplementation("mx.managers::IActiveWindowManager") as ActiveWindowManager;
        var index : int = systemManager.getChildIndex(popup); 
        var newIndex : int = index;
        var n : int = windowManager.forms.length;
        for (var j : int = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            var f : DisplayObject = windowManager.forms[j];
            if (systemManager.contains(f))
                if (systemManager.getChildIndex(f) > index)
                    newIndex = Math.max(systemManager.getChildIndex(f), newIndex);
        }
        if (newIndex > index)
        {
            systemManager.setChildIndex(popup, newIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a test example:

```
        import helperClasses.PopupHelper;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        import spark.components.TitleWindow;

        public function showPopup() : void
        {   
            var popup1 : TitleWindow = new TitleWindow();
            popup1.title = "Popup 1";
            new PopupHelper(popup1, systemManager).forceToFront();
            var popup2 : TitleWindow = new TitleWindow();
            popup2.title = "Popup 2";
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup1, this, false);
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup2, this, false);
            PopUpManager.bringToFront(popup1);
            popup1.x = 20;
            popup1.y = 20;
        }
```

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what I wanted, but it got me headed in the right direction. Thank you!